# Render partial Error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

I have the following method, to throw a 404 if the request is made for xml,json or html.

```
def render_error(code, status_type = nil)
  @error = ErrorMessage.new(code, status_type)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any(:html, :json) { render @error.partial, status: @error.status }
    format.any { render html: ErrorMessage.new(404).partial }
  end
end
```

This is the partial method

```
def partial
  'messages/show'
end
```

The same thing works if I use `format.any { head 404, "content_type" => 'text/plain' }` instead of `format.any { render html: ErrorMessage.new(404).partial }`.This is the error I get.

```
Missing template errors/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :haml]}
```

when I request for `test.xml`
 But I want to use stylized html error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: We don't know. What is your error?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I forgot to paste the error here. Have updated the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
    format.any { render :html => 'messages/show', object: ErrorMessage.new(404,nil) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. this worked
`format.any { render file: @error.partial, content_type: 'text/html', formats: [:html],  status: @error.status }`